How to do "press [specific input] to start"
My project is a small text-based RPG game in the terminal. I would like to create a title start screen, it shows the title and its the means to start the game by just pressing an input. How can I bind the ENTER key to start the game, so the user would need to press enter to start the first chapter?
So far what I've learned from rust regarding user input is read_line, but it doesn't really work the way I want, yes the user can still just press enter and start but it's an instance of a string as well, which means they can just type anything and it would look weird, not really how these things work in games.
Here's the code so far:
use std::io;

fn main() {

    let mut enter = String::new();

    println!("###################");
    println!("      MY GAME      ");
    println!("###################");
    println!();
    println!("Press enter to begin.");

    io::stdin()
    .read_line(&mut enter)
    .expect("Invalid input.");

    print!("{}[2J", 27 as char); //This is a screen cleaner
}


Instead of print!("{}[2J", 27 as char); you can just do print!("\u{1b}[2J");. Also, it's not clear at all what you expect the system to do if they type stuff before pressing enter. Based on what you've described in your question, the code you've presented does what you wish. So what is the actual problem with this code that you need help with?

Hello, so, the problem is i just wish to have the user ONLY press the enter key and nothing else to initiate the rest of the program, what currently happens is: the user is able to 1. type things AND then 2. press enter, and i wish the first part of that wasn't there, literally JUST press enter. Sorry if i didn't made clear enough, thanks for the help!

You need a TUI/terminal manipulation library. There are several of those for Rust. Perhaps try crossterm (but I'm no Rust guru).

In general, if you write a console application (in Rust or any other language), you do not really control the terminal, so usually the user can always enter something, and it may appear on the screen. (e.g., on Linux, run sleep 10, and then start typing...)
Secondly you use io::stdin, in Linux stdin usually is a buffered input; that is too high-level for your purpose. In C, there is the non-standard conio.h for low-level control, I don't know if Rust has an equivalent...
Thirdly (maybe that is already going too far), maybe what you want is to disable the terminal's echo on the user's input, like stty -echo.
Anyway, somehow you need some deeper control on some peripheral device (the terminal, the keyboard) while writing a console application (which abstracts away the actual peripherals). In the comments of your OP there were suggestions on Rust libraries for that...

Since you are already using ANSI escape codes, a match I found on that was SO-45610046: Disable echo and set raw terminal mode via ANSI escape sequence (talking C), maybe that is of help?
